# Passing Parameter in Stored Procedure 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

The SP is not treating @AgeBand parameter correctly.
How do i pass that parameter?

```
Alter Procedure sp_Dialer_Analysis
    @AgeBand Varchar(50),
    @Gender Varchar(50),
    @Weekday Varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

Select @AgeBand,@Gender,@Weekday,SUM(RPC)
from TableA a
left join TableB b
on a.[Contact Info] = b.MSI
where a.date >= '2017-01-01'
and b.gender = @Gender and b.AgeBand in (@AgeBand)
and DATENAME(WEEKDAY,a.date) = @Weekday

END

Exec sp_Dialer_Analysis "'50-54','55-59'",'F','Monday'
```

"'50-54','55-59'" is the issue.
Kindly suggest some alternative.

Comment: Hmmm. . . The query is treating age band correctly.  You just are expecting the wrong thing.  You are passing in a single value in a string.

Comment: are you intend to have single quotes around both `ageBand` value? or else you need to pass two values

Comment: Also, do not call your procedures **sp_**. Read more [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: My question is can we use AgeBand in (X,Y,Z) in stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition `b.AgeBand in (@AgeBand)` will not work,

try using `CHARINDEX(b.AgeBand,@AgeBand) > 0`

Comment: It will work like string_split, it will check char index in the string.

Comment: @SHD - Awesome one dear :D

Comment: STRING_SPLIT is the correct method as told by Rachel, but it will only support 2016, otherwise we need to create custom function.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an array in to stored procedure like that, doubly so using double quotes (")

Your best bet is to either run the procedure multiple times (yuck, performance hit) or split the array out using either a home brewed Split function or the new `String_Split` function in Sql Server 2016

Perhaps something like this (not tested, off the top of my head)

```
Alter Procedure sp_Dialer_Analysis
    @AgeBand Varchar(50),
    @Gender Varchar(50),
    @Weekday Varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

Select @AgeBand,@Gender,@Weekday,SUM(RPC)
from TableA a
Cross Apply String_Split(@AgeBand, ',') As s
left join TableB b
on a.[Contact Info] = b.MSI
where a.date >= '2017-01-01'
and b.gender = @Gender
And b.ageband = s.value
and DATENAME(WEEKDAY,a.date) = @Weekday

END

Exec sp_Dialer_Analysis '50-54,55-59','F','Monday'
```

*Not tried SHD's answer but prima-facia I think it deserves merit... and may be a better answer*

Answer (score 0):

I think OP is asking about escape characters.

Please try this : `Exec sp_Dialer_Analysis '''50-54'',''55-59''','F','Monday'`